# Installing High Sierra on a Linux machine

Tags: install, unix, high-sierra

I currently have (Arch) Linux on my MacBook Air (2012), and I want to install High Sierra on an external drive, so [I can run the new `eficheck`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299652/testing-efi-integrity-under-linux). How do I do that, and without disturbing my existing Linux installation?

In particular I'm worried that the installation would mess up my current booting scheme.  It would be fixable, but I don't have time for that kind of problem now.  If it would just change the efibootmgr order, I know how to alter that.

Comment: Does your MacBook support internet recovery? If so, that and an external boot capable drive would do the trick to run the installer.

Comment: Download High Sierra on a second Mac, create a 10.13 USB installer, boot your Mac from this thumb drive and install 10.13 to the external drive.

Comment: @bmike Internet Recovery will install the original OS X/macOS the Mac came with.

Comment: Not necessarily but possibly @klanomath. https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204904 There’s even a single user mode boot combined with internet recovery to get someone a shell from the internet.

Comment: @bmike hmm a new shortcut ;-)

Comment: @bmike, this would leave my linux alone?